# Neo4J java driver - Out of memory with correct query

Tags: java, neo4j, out-of-memory, driver

I am currently confronted with a Neo4J problem and I don't really know where to look for the answer, as I'm calling the java driver at a low level and everything seems to check out.

The situation:

- running Neo4J in docker (3.3), gave it 14G of memory
- using java 8
- it's working great with OGM, processing large amounts of data and lots of queries
- talking to it through java, neo4j-ogm-core 3.1.0, neo4j-java-driver 1.5.2

Now, I'm restructuring my project to make use of the low-level java driver instead of the OGM driver, for performance reasons. Queries such as the following one run fine:

```
MATCH (s:Sentence)<-[:SENTENCE_OF]-(:Paragraph)<-[:CONTAINS]-(d:Document) WHERE id(d) = {docid} RETURN s.sentence as t
parameters = {docid=2681031}
```

One of the queries however hangs:

```
MATCH  (w0:Word) , (w0:Word)<-[:CONTAINS_WORD]-(:Sentence)-[:SENTENCE_OF]-(:Paragraph)<-[:CONTAINS]-(d:Document)  WHERE w0.originalTextLower = {wT0} AND  id(d) = {docid}  RETURN w0
parameters = {wT0=abo, docid=2681032}
```

If I run the same query through the web interface, the query executes fine and returns no results. If I run it through the java driver, it jacks up the cpu usage to 100% and runs itself into the ground:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 875036672 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /hs_err_pid378.log
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x000000063b400000, 875036672, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
```

I call this statement through the org.neo4j.driver.v1.Session object, as follows:

```
session.run(statementTemplate, parameters);
```

I'd already appreciate a hint as to where to look further. The query seems fine, I'm running the latest software and drivers, ... the only thing I can't check is what the driver itself is doing below the water.

Comment: Did you create an index for `:Word(originalTextLower)`?

Comment: Yes I did, in any case, the same query through the Web interface executes in a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: Made some progress: I create the Bolt session through the following call: GraphDatabase.driver("bolt://" + hostname + ":7687", AuthTokens.basic(username, password)); The query I showed in the OP is the 6th in line (the first 5 execute fine). For each query, I request a session from the driver object: driver.getSession(). However, if I recreate the Driver object, the query succeeds (this launches a new connection pool for each query). If I just use a session requested from the same Driver object, it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem: the neo4j-java-driver does not handle nested queries. I had one loop that iterated over the results of 1 query. In that loop, it used the same Session object to execute another query. OGM does not complain in that situation, but neo4j-java-driver does.